# Error code 1093:Error in Sql Syntax

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql .

```
update voting_table
Set VOTING_STATUS = 1
where  CE_ID = 15813 

and

VOTING_PK = 
(SELECT VOTING_PK FROM voting_table
ORDER BY VOTING_PK DESC
LIMIT 1) ;
```

But the editor shows me the following error :

```
Error code 1093, SQL state HY000: You can't specify target table 'voting_table' for update in FROM clause
```

How can I overcome the error ? Please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these SQL will helpful to you.

```
update voting_table as table_1, (SELECT VOTING_PK FROM voting_table ORDER BY VOTING_PK DESC LIMIT 1) as table_2  
where table_1.VOTING_PK = table_2.VOTING_PK and CE_ID = 15813 
Set VOTING_STATUS = 1
```

Thank you.